# Parse 4 digit code from binary hash in C#

Tags: c#, binary, sha

6 bits from the beginning of hash and 7 bits from the end of hash are taken. The resulting 13 bits are transformed into decimal number and printed out. The code is a decimal 4-digits number in range 0000...8192, always 4 digits are displayed (e.g. 0041).

Example:

- Hash value: 2f665f6a6999e0ef0752e00ec9f453adf59d8cb6
- Binary representation of hash: **0010 11**11 0110 0110 1111 .... 1000 1100 1**011 0110**
- code – binary value: 0010110110110
- code – decimal value: 1462

Example No.2:

- Hash value: otr+8gszp9ey/gcCu4Q8ValEbewEb5zL+mvyKakl1Pp7S1Be3klDYh0RcLktBpgs6VbbgCTjsmvjEZtMbUkaEg==
- (calculations)
- code – decimal value: 5138

With example no.1 I'm not sure which one SHA used. But the second one is definitely Sha512 and I can't get the desired code **5138**.

Steps I made:

- Created sha:

```
 var sha = SHA512.Create();
```

- Computed hash 3 ways (str -> hash value from above):

```
1) var _hash = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str));

2) var _hash = sha.ComputeHash(Convert.FromBase64String(str));

3) Call procedure: string stringifiedHash = ToBinaryString(Encoding.UTF8, str);
static string ToBinaryString(Encoding encoding, string text)
{
   string.Join("", encoding.GetBytes(text).Select(n => Convert.ToString(n, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')));
}
```

- Stringified (1 and 2 hash) to binary value string (This part redone from Java project with exact same calculations) :

```
(((0xFC & _hash[0]) << 5) | (_hash[_hash.Length - 1] & 0x7F)).ToString("0000")
```

- OR substring stringifiedHash and take 6 bits from begining and 7 from end. And then convert:

```
Convert.ToInt({value from substring and join}, 2)
```

But every try returned not correct answer. Where I made an mistake while trying to parse desired code.

Answer (score 0):

Your bitwise logic is incorrect.

```
upper = 0b111111
lower = 0b0010101
value = upper << 5 | lower
value = 0b11111110101 // this is not the value you wanted it never goes beyond 11 bits.
```

Essentially the above operation looks like this

```
// Notice the lowest two bytes of the top will overwrite the top two bytes of the bottom.
  0b11111100000  
|     0b0010101
-------------------
  0b11111110101 // Only 11 bits...
```

You need room for the final 7 bits after your | operation. If you only bit shift 5 times when you | with the lower 7 bits you will overwrite 2 of them.

So, updating the shift in your code should solve the problem.

```
public static string Get13FormattedBitches ( Hash hash ) 
{ 
    UInt16 upper = hash[0] & 0xFC;
    UInt16 lower = hash[hash.Length - 1] & 0x7F;
    UInt16 value = (upper << 7) | lower;
    return value.ToString ( "0000" );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. After your answer, I saw where made a mistake...  

```
(((0xFC & _hash[0]) << 5) | (_hash[_hash.Length - 1] & 0x7F)).ToString("0000")
```
This function was actually good. The mistake was with ComputeHash function. After converting primary string from Base64 I got the desired hash and I don't need to compute hash again.